# Large, consistent residues after STL decomposition signifies non periodicity?

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, stl-decomposition

I used STL decomposition on the power consumption data from an air-conditioner over a period of 10 weeks. I would expect this data to be periodic over a week. What I am able to observe from the data is that the curve has huge residual values when compared to seasonality or trend.

Does this mean that the data that I have does not accurately represent the weekly cycle of air-conditioner usage? Or is this model still good enough to be used for anomaly detection? Also, the trend seems to have a periodicity. What does this signify?

[STL Decomposition of Power Consumption (freq = 1 week)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBW1W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case Closed.

It was indeed the case that the data does not accurately represent the weekly cycles of AC usage. The AC was being used on whims.